# Gemini Pro API Blocking Replies

Tags: python, google-gemini

Running Gemini AP added code to avoid blocking but getting blocked. My commands do not get blocked when using ChatGPT?

**Code in Python**

```
def get_gemini_response(question, safety_settings=None):
    # If safety settings are not provided, set it to 'block_none' for all categories
    if safety_settings is None:
        safety_settings = {
            'SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT': 'block_none',
            'HATE_SPEECH': 'block_none',
            'HARASSMENT': 'block_none',
            'DANGEROUS_CONTENT': 'block_none'
        }
```

**Reply from Gemini Pro**

```
BlockedPromptException: block_reason: SAFETY safety_ratings { category: HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT probability: NEGLIGIBLE } safety_ratings { category: HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH probability: HIGH } safety_ratings { category: HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT probability: NEGLIGIBLE } safety_ratings { category: HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT probability: NEGLIGIBLE }
```

The [safety settings page](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/python_quickstart#safety_settings) from Google implies it may still get blocked:

```
Now provide the same prompt to the model with newly configured safety settings, **and you may get a response.**


response = model.generate_content('[Questionable prompt here]',
                                  safety_settings={'HARASSMENT':'block_none'})
```

Comment: From [Safety settings](https://ai.google.dev/docs/safety_setting_gemini): “*Adjusting to lower safety settings will trigger a more indepth review process of your application.*” Have you been through this review? If not, can you elaborate on why you feel it should work anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue trying to process descriptions of injuries and incidents.

The `safety_settings` argument takes a list of `SafetySetting` objects.

1. You have to import these classes:

   ```
   from vertexai.preview.generative_models import (
       HarmCategory, 
       HarmBlockThreshold )
   from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1beta1.types.content import SafetySetting
   ```
2. Use it in `safety_settings` attribute as follows:

   ```
    model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")
    response: GenerationResponse = model.generate_content(
    prompt_text.format(text),
    generation_config={
        "max_output_tokens": 2048,
        "temperature": 0,
        "top_p": 1,

    },
    safety_settings = [
        SafetySetting(
            category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT,
            threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        ),
        SafetySetting(
            category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT,
            threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        ),
        SafetySetting(
            category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH,
            threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        ),
        SafetySetting(
            category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT,
            threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        ),
    ]
   ```

   )

Comment: have to try this...when get a chance. thanks for answer.

Comment: tried this and got to work temporarily without a block, but unstable as it blocked about an hour later.

Comment: I also get blocks, not even loading something edgy like you accident descriptions, just protocol  details, absolutely nothing explicit in any way in the docs I'm loading, reported this as a bug on the Vertex ai Gemini beta.