# Why does Google Vertex API Blocking Responses Even with Safety Off?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am attempting to use evaluate how Gemini performs on the Learned Hands dataset, which prompts to see if a given post has a specific legal issue included.

My code is the following:

```
from vertexai.preview import generative_models
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel

prompt = """
Does the post discuss dealing with domestic violence and abuse, including getting protective orders, enforcing them, understanding abuse, reporting abuse, and getting resources and status if there is abuse? 

Post: Like the title states when I was 19 I was an escort for about a year. I was groomed into it by a man I met online. Tony. When I met him I was under the impression he wanted to be my sugar daddy. Instead I was greeted by him and a couple of his girls at a nice hotel. One girl in particular was the star of the show. We were all taken care of by her. Her name was Mo. They promised up to 1,000$ a day for my services. I didn’t have a choice I had nothing. We were forced to see up to 8 guys in a single day. Then cut our profit with Tony. However eventually I came to my senses, took my cash and cut ties. It was incredibly corrupt. They remained bitter at me, sending the occasional threatening message. Very petty nothing worth worrying about. He had my real information such as my email &amp; full name. Cut to about a year later and a former client sends me a news article. Seems Tony got greedy and started his own service. Except he had really fucked up. He was a third striker caught with an underage girl. Mo lured her in so she was also caught and they went to jail. I was completely removed from their life when they made these choices. Cut to three days ago. I get an email from a detective. He knows my full name. He wants to speak to me immediately. Wants to know everything I know. What the heck do I do!!! I’m terrified. 
Label:
"""

model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")
safety_config = {
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
    generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
}

chat = model.start_chat()
response = chat.send_message(
    prompt,
    safety_settings=safety_config,
)

print(response.candidates[0].text)
```

Unfortunately, this produces the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/langston/Documents/Eval/vertex_sample.py", line 25, in <module>
    response = chat.send_message(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/langston/miniconda3/envs/prl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py", line 709, in send_message
    return self._send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/langston/miniconda3/envs/prl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py", line 806, in _send_message
    if response.candidates[0].finish_reason not in _SUCCESSFUL_FINISH_REASONS:
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After digging into the raw API response, I assume this error is due to content moderation.

Two questions:

- Why is the moderation not disabled by my `safety_settings`?
- Why is the error message not better?

Comment: From the error it seems like the list is empty, can you try with some other prompt example?

Comment: With other prompts it works normally, it's just this specific prompt that produces the error. Also note that the list being empty is within the vertexai package not my code. To be honest the error message just seems to be a bug in vertexai (someone not putting in a len(response.candidates) > 0 check).

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723993/gemini-pro-api-blocking-replies) link?

Answer (score 0):

Samue issue, they do not want people using BLOCK_NONE, in my case the word is probably frac, which is not even a bad word.